# Почему после перестановки последний элемент обращается в ноль? Нашел ошибку, но пока не исправил

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Подскажите по массивам

```
String[] arrOfSymbols = new String[listOfStr.size()]; 
String[] arrOfSymbolsFinal = new String[listOfStr.size()];

for(int j=0,k=0; j < arrOfSymbols.length;j++ ){
    for(int i=0; i< keyCollum.length; i++){
        if((keyCollum.length*j+keyCollum[i]) < arrOfSymbols.length && (keyCollum.length*j+i) < arrOfSymbols.length) {
            arrOfSymbolsFinal[keyCollum.length*j+keyCollum[i]] = arrOfSymbols[keyCollum.length*j+i];  //Смотреть сюда
            // k++;
            // System.out.println(k);
            System.out.println(keyCollum.length*j+keyCollum[i] + "     " + (keyCollum.length*j+i) 
                  + "   " + arrOfSymbols[keyCollum.length*j+i] + "     " + arrOfSymbolsFinal[keyCollum.length*j+keyCollum[i]]);
            //  System.out.println();
        }
    }
  }

  for(int i=0; i < arrOfSymbols.length; i++){
      System.out.println("final: "+arrOfSymbolsFinal[i]);  //и сбда
  }

  for(int i=0; i < arrOfSymbols.length;i++){
      System.out.println(arrOfSymbols[i]);
  }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему после перестановки последний элемент обращается в 0? Строкой ниже (в цикле где записывается в массив) вывожу этот же элемент, он не пустой. Спасибо.

upd: Нашел ошибку, проблемма не в массиве, а в If'e. Думаю как исправить...
upd2: Короч блоки символом, должны делится на ключ без остатка, я просто в классе который шифрует, запустил цикл, который пока не делится без остатка, добавляет пустые строки.

Comment: что должно быть в проверке?

Comment: в кратце, есть ключ( int[] keyCollum = {4,5,3,1,2,0} ; )  и по нему нужно переставить строки местами. Получается я длинну ключа умножаю на переменную внешнего цикла и прибавляю внутреннюю переменную. А условие добавил, чтобы не вылезать за рамки массива. Я могу выложить весь код проекта, если не будете пинать ногами за корявость и извращение))

Comment: почему у вас 2 цикла?

Comment: цикл в цикле... Не смог придумать ничего проще, для перестановки по ключу. А внизу два цикла только ради того, чтобы понять, что не так отрабатывает. [вот весь код](https://github.com/kkamik/Example/tree/master/src/by/filatov)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Может так

```
for(int j=0,k=0; j < arrOfSymbols.length/keyCollum.length;j++ ){
    for(int i=0; i< keyCollum.length; i++){
        if((keyCollum.length*j+keyCollum[i]) < arrOfSymbols.length 
        && (keyCollum.length*j+i) < arrOfSymbols.length) {
           arrOfSymbolsFinal[keyCollum.length*j+keyCollum[i]] =
               arrOfSymbols[keyCollum.length*j+i];  //Смотреть сюда
            System.out.println(keyCollum.length*j+keyCollum[i] + "     " +
               (keyCollum.length*j+i) + "   " + 
               arrOfSymbols[keyCollum.length*j+i] + "     " +
               arrOfSymbolsFinal[keyCollum.length*j+keyCollum[i]]);
        }
    }
}
```

Там только хвост будет.

Comment: ненене, ток что понял где ошибка, она в if'e, http://pixs.ru/showimage/Bezimyanni_9577388_18873097.png

Comment: почти так, спасибо за идею, я обновил на git'e, но он не до конца адекватно работает, но работает!!))). В любом случае спасибо за идею, завтра уже в нормальный вид приведу.

Comment: для одекватной работы у вас блоки должны быть такой длины, чтобы размер главного массива делился на размер ключа без остатка

Comment: Точно! Когда делал перестановку по столбцам, сделал это, а тут как-то забылся... =) Все заработало, сейчас буду приводить в нормальный вид это все.